# iReports and grails. set javabeans data source and connection

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport, grails-domain-class, jasper-plugin

I have some problems to configure iReports, I´m using `iReport4.8.0` (I tried `iReport4.7.1` before and the same problem happened) and `grails ggts 3.0.0`.

I have a domain class called Consulta in a package called consultas, I want to list them and create a report using ireports, I´ve followed the steps I found in a book: Beginning Groovy
and Grails From Novice to Professional CHAPTER 9 it says that create a report from groovy clases is very easy (in theory it is) you just have to create a jar with the classes compiled and place it in the reports lib directory, then  select "javabeans set data source  option from data connections where the only field to fill is the name, it says to set the others blank, when I test it an error pop-up appears saying ClassNotFoundError, I'm sure there are some missing steps but i don't know which.

in my consulta controller I have this code:

```
def report ={
    def consultas = Consulta.list()
    chain(controller: "jasper", action: "index", model: [data: consultas], params:params)       
}
```

and I think jassper plugins are OK.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of ClassNotFound? You put your jar in the lib folder?

Comment: yes, I did, I put a jar with my domain classes in the ireports lib folder an added it to the classpath.

Comment: I couldn't find the stacktrace, the error apears when I test the conection so I can't continue

Comment: Then is something related with your datasource and not jasper. Can you post your config, and the complete error message?

Comment: finally I got it, it was much easier than what I was trying. I set empty datasource and put fields $F{name} and... it works! I was trying to configure the data source connection as javabeans and it wasn't needed